# set option selected using php value

Tags: php, html

I have HTML form which have select options like below

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Select your occupation:</label>
    <select class="form-control" name = "occupation" required>
    <?php if ($row[occupation] == 0){

    }?>
        <option  value="0">Parent</option>
        <option  value="1">Teacher</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I want

> option selected called Parent if ($row[occupation] == 0) else want
>   show Teacher as selected

. I am new in PHP and does not know how I can I do it. Let me know if someone can help me for do it.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to echo `selected='selected'` based on the value of `$row['occupation']`, like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Select your occupation:</label>
    <select class="form-control" name = "occupation" required>
        <option value="0"<?php if($row['occupation'] == 0){ echo " selected='selected'"; } ?>>Parent</option>
        <option  value="1"<?php if($row['occupation'] == 1){ echo " selected='selected'"; } ?>>Teacher</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I think the use of ternary would make it slightly easier to read: `<?= $row['occupation'] == 0 ? 'selected' : '' ?>`. That's just my opinion, though :-)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Okay, I misinterpreted your comment as *do this in every option `<?= $row['occupation'] == 0 ? 'selected' : '' ?>`*. I got your point now, yeah, your method does indeed work. Deleted my previous comment. :-)

Comment: @RajuBhatt - It the answer solved your issue, you should accept it so others know the question has been resolved and to give the user that helped you their much deserved rep.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this one.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Select your occupation:</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="occupation" required>
        <option value="0" <?php if ($row['occupation'] == 0) { echo 'selected'; } ?>>Parent</option>
        <option value="1" <?php if ($row['occupation'] == 1) { echo 'selected'; } ?>>Teacher</option>
    </select>
</div>
```